# React js error: A form label must be associated with a control

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, lint

I found some topics about this error but non of them solve the problem..

here is my code:

```
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="variationType"
          value="pa_pay_baga"
          onChange={(e) => {
            props.handleChange(e, 'pa_pay_baga');
          }}
          className="btn-check"
          id="btn-check5"
        />
        <label htmlFor="btn-check5" className="btn btn-primary-border">
          bla bla
        </label>
```

And this is my lint configuration:

```
 "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 0, {
  "components": [ "Label" ],
  "required": {
    "some": [ "id" ]
  }
}],
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

This eslint rule is actually [[deprecated] label-has-for](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md) - I would adjust this to turn off the rule and enable the new rule [label-has-associated-control](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md) e.g.

```json
 "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": "off",
"label-has-associated-control": "warn",
```

This new rule requires them to share a common parent, so configure it like this:

```html
<label htmlFor="btn-check5" className="btn btn-primary-border">
       bla bla

        <input
          type="radio"
          name="variationType"
          value="pa_pay_baga"
          onChange={(e) => {
            props.handleChange(e, 'pa_pay_baga');
          }}
          className="btn-check"
          id="btn-check5"
        />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this Github issue](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/759), shortly seems the message is misleading and require to have label as a parent of input as well:

```
     
        <label htmlFor="btn-check5" className="btn btn-primary-border">
          <input
          type="radio"
          name="variationType"
          value="pa_pay_baga"
          onChange={(e) => {
            props.handleChange(e, 'pa_pay_baga');
          }}
          className="btn-check"
          id="btn-check5"
        />
        </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue of the eslist warning of `A form label must be associated with a control.`

Then I self realized the solution by looking at the explaination of @Kieran Osgood.

SO you need to make sure that `<input>` tag goes inside `<label>` tag and also add `htmlFor` attribute with matching `id` for the `<label>` tag.

This is how your code should look like :

```js
          <label htmlFor="btn-check5" className="btn btn-primary-border">
            bla bla
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="variationType"
              value="pa_pay_baga"
              onChange={(e) => {
                props.handleChange(e, 'pa_pay_baga');
              }}
              className="btn-check"
              id="btn-check5"
            />
          </label>
```